# Python список кортежей, получить второй элемент каждого кортежа

Tags: python, список

Есть список кортежей:

> ```
> [('Магазин', 'railway_fork'), ('Игры', 'games'), ('Информация о боте', 'menu_item'), 
>  ('Пополнить счет', 'info')]
> ```

Нужно получить только вторые элементы кортежей:

> ```
> [('railway_fork'), ('games'), ('railway_fork'), ('info')]
> ```

Как это можно сделать?

Comment: Так `[('railway_fork'), ('games'), ('railway_fork'), ('info')]` или `['railway_fork', 'games', 'railway_fork', 'info']`? Первый вариант похож на список кортежей

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Такой вариант по скорости должен быть быстрее всех:

```
a = [('Магазин', 'railway_fork'),
     ('Игры', 'games'),
     ('Информация о боте', 'menu_item'),
     ('Пополнить счет', 'info')]    
print([x[1] for x in a])
```

если надо список через запятую то так:

```
print(*[x[1] for x in a], sep=",")
```

Бинго!
Однако похоже лучше воспользоваться словарем в вашем случае. И вероятно - с самого начала )) по смыслу данных. Но вам виднее.
Вот такой вариант с преобразованием в словарь:

```
d=dict(a)
print(*list(d.values()))
```

Comment: Если среди элементов с индексом 0 найдутся одинаковые значения - фигня получится, а в остальном со словарем решение идеально (ИМХО)

Answer (score 2):

Через comprehension и без лишних преобразований в словарь:

```
lst = [('Магазин', 'railway_fork'), ('Игры', 'games'), ('Информация о боте', 'menu_item'), ('Пополнить счет', 'info')]
print([y for x, y, *z in lst])
```

На выходе:

```
['railway_fork', 'games', 'menu_item', 'info']
```

Comment: А `*z` зачем нужен? Если `x` не используется, лучше на `_` подменить: `[y for _, y in lst]`

Comment: @gil9red а *z - на случай, если в кортежах более двух элементов, как тут уже было отмечено. Что касается замены x на _, то это же абсолютно не существенно.

Comment: `как тут уже было отмечено`, кем отмечено?  Автор ничего такого не говорил, это уже вы перестраховываетесь :)

Answer (score 1):

Через множественный `for`:

```
second_elems = []

# Может быть больше 2 элементов
for k, v in tuple_list:
    # k - 0-й элемент
    second_elems.append((v,))
```

> Нужно получить только вторые элементы кортежей: [('railway_fork'), ('games'), ('railway_fork'), ('info')]

Я так понял, что вам нужен именно список кортежей, поэтому в `second_elems.append((v))` я добавляю кортеж с единственным элементом.

Comment: `.append((v))` это тоже самое что `.append(v)`, а чтобы кортеж с одним элементом добавить: `.append((v,))`

Answer (score 1):

Можно через zip

```
lst = [('Магазин', 'railway_fork'), ('Игры', 'games'), 
       ('Информация о боте', 'menu_item'), ('Пополнить счет', 'info')]

print([(item,) for item in list(zip(*lst))[1]])      
# [('railway_fork',), ('games',), ('menu_item',), ('info',)]

print(*[item for item in list(zip(*lst))[1]])
# railway_fork games menu_item info

print([item for item in list(zip(*lst))[1]])
# ['railway_fork', 'games', 'menu_item', 'info']
```

Или так:

```
print([lst[i][1] for i in range(len(lst))])
# ['railway_fork', 'games', 'menu_item', 'info']
```

Answer (score 0):

```
a = [('Магазин', 'railway_fork'), ('Игры', 'games'),
     ('Информация о боте', 'menu_item'),
     ('Пополнить счет', 'info')]

print(a[0][1], ",", a[1][1],",", a[2][1],",", a[3][1])
```

Comment: Очень неудобное решение. Элементов может быть как больше, так и меньше 4.

Comment: В данном вопросе указан конкретный кортеж ,а не задан что в кортеже может быть н-ое количество элементов, я отталкиваюсь от вопроса)))

Comment: Предложенные на StackOverflow решения могут быть использованы также и другими разработчиками, поэтому я предложил более "универсальный" ответ.